# JSF Redirect page based on User role

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, spring-security

I have two types of admin.
Super admin and normal admin.

Both start on the page admin.xhtml.

I want to forward super admin users to super-admin.xhtml and normal admin to normal-admin.xhtml.

How do I do this in JSF (I'm using Spring Security)?

Comment: On what action do you want to redirect to different page by being on admin.xhtml page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with JSF, but assuming it functions under the hood just like a Spring MVC JSP application, you can have your controller deliver a different page depending on the role(s) held by the user:

```
@RequestMapping("/admin.xhtml")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SUPERADMIN')")
public String getAdminPage(Modelmap model, Principal principal) {
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
    for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
        if (authority.toString() == "ROLE_SUPERADMIN") { return "superadminpage"; }
    }
    //no need to check for admin privileges, since the annotation took care of that
    //if you're not using annotations (or @PostAuthorize), you'd have to capture the
    //'admin' role as well, and adjust the return statements accordingly.
    return "adminpage";
}
```